# access symbol in "external" swf AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I can do 2-things. Load an external swf, and change the color of an object. When I put these two things together, it doesn't work. **How do I change the color of the loaded swf?**
I want to access instance names in loaded swf files.

**WHAT I WAS TOLD**
**I have to package it and set up a class paths.  Is there an easy way for now?**

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/ball.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/ball.jpg)

**ball.swf**

```
"white ball on the stage named blueball"
```

**load.fla**

```
//load ball.swf
var bgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
bg_mc.addChild(bgLoader);
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ball.swf");
bgLoader.load(bgURL);

//change color of ball to blue "code works in ball.swf" 
var myColor:ColorTransform = blueball.transform.colorTransform; 
myColor.color = 0x066ccf; 
blueball.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
```

**ERROR #1120**
access of undefined property

**NOTE**
swf files are all actionscript-3. I've played with the publishing and security settings.

**EXPERIMENT** "to understand using symbols in external swf files"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the "root", after the swf is loaded you can reach the timeline scope using root. Consider the following:

```
var bgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
bg_mc.addChild(bgLoader);
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ball.swf");
bgLoader.load(bgURL);
bgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    // use root to reach the timeline scope of the loaded swf
    var loadedBlueball:MovieClip = event.target.content.root.blueball;
    //change color of ball to blue "code works in ball.swf" 
    var myColor:ColorTransform = loadedBlueball.transform.colorTransform; 
    myColor.color = 0x066ccf; 
    loadedBlueball.transform.colorTransform = myColor;

    // just adding the ball to stage, you might want to add all swf
    addChild(loadedBlueball);
}
```

"In ActionScript 3 the root property refers to the main timeline of the loaded SWF (and not the timeline of the SWF which loaded the other SWF)." *from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/cookbook/timeline_root.html*

Comment: I had this problem in Flash 8 with ActionScript 2, and using myContainerClip._root fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its because the swf isnt loaded when you try to change the color. You just need to use event and it should work

```
import flash.events.*;
```

[...]

```
var bgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
bgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, setMyBallColor); 
bg_mc.addChild(bgLoader);
var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ball.swf");
bgLoader.load(bgURL);
```

[...]

```
function setMyBallColor() {
//change color of ball to blue "code works in ball.swf" 
var myColor:ColorTransform = blueball.transform.colorTransform; // bg_mc.blueball.transform.colorTransform; ?
myColor.color = 0x066ccf; 
blueball.transform.colorTransform = myColor; // same
}
```

Comment: Loader does not have a "complete" event -- you have to add the listener to Loader's contentLoaderInfo member:

bgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, setMyBallColor);

Comment: Yea, I added the event listener, but got the same error. I took the symbol from "ball.swf" and put it in "load.swf" and THERE'S NO ERRORS, just to white balls. What's missing? I'm still not accessing the external swf.

Comment: oops missed that

Not sure but to access the blueball instance i think you need to use getChildAt(0)